# Vertical scroll Page to next image on click

Tags: scrollto

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I would be very grateful!
I've searched the Forum but i couldn't find the right way to get it working.

I'm searching for a solution to cycle vertically trough images like this example here:

http://www.mirkoborsche.com/2013-Superpaper-No43

The structure of my site looks like this:

```
<div class="img-cont">

<img alt="image-1.jpg" src="uploads/image-1.jpg" class="progressive" />
<img alt="image-2.jpg" src="uploads/image-2.jpg" class="progressive" />
<img alt="image-3.jpg" src="uploads/image-3.jpg" class="progressive" />
<img alt="image-4.jpg" src="uploads/image-4.jpg" class="progressive" />

</div>
```

Many thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jQuery you can animate `scrollTop`. Here's an example.
http://papermashup.com/jquery-page-scrolling/

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the Link. Thats nearly what i'm searching for ... but i need a method to scroll up and down the page without giving each image a class.

Comment: just specify the amount then: `scrollTop: "+=200px"`.

Comment: also something like `scrollTop: $(".images").eq(counter).offset().top` with a `counter++` could work for you

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each of the images in an [anchor](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html) tag `<a>` and use javascript like this:

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
}
```

Then you can call this function with an `onClick()` on something or with a button, for instance.

**EDIT:**

If you need an *easing* effect to transition smoothly, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275329/jquery-scrollto-easing) answer here in SO.

Comment: well from the example he gave i'm guessing he wants a smooth scroll. `location.hash` is jumpy

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to check out the example... It's blocked with my firewall at work. I'll update the answer...